# 1 var works, 1 doesn't. Why?

Tags: php, echo, var

Before I start I know I'm using outdated methods and should learn PDO...

```
<?php 
    $f = mysql_query("SELECT featured, date_featured FROM pins WHERE id='$pinDetails->id'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($g = mysql_fetch_array($f)) 
        $feature = $g['featured'];

    $on = $g['date_featured'];
?>
```

But when I echo...

`<?php echo $feature; ?>` works, but `<?php echo $on; ?>` doesn't.

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Doesn't means any error?

Comment: So what value does `date_featured` have in result?

Comment: the value is a datestamp in Y-m-d H:i:s format, but nothing shows, no errors, just blank.

Comment: For one you need to use `fetch_assoc`, not `fetch_array`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky `fetch_array` returns an array with both numeric and associative keys (haven't I corrected you about this before?)

Comment: it's not printed because is out of while() loop

Comment: Otherwise it could be a `false` or `null` value, which both evaluates to nothing...

Comment: @Joke_Sense10 You're joking, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't put braces around the body of your `while` loop, so your code is equivalent to:

```
while ($g = mysql_fetch_array($f)) {
    $feature = $g['featured'];
}
$on = $g['date_featured'];
```

So it's not trying to set `$on` until the loop finishes. And it finishes when `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `false`, which it assigns to `$g`. So you're doing:

```
$on = false['date_featured'];
```

Since you're obviously just getting one row, you don't need a `while` loop. Just write:

```
$g = mysql_fetch_assoc($f);
$feature = $g['featured'];
$on = $g['date_featured'];
```

Why did you write a loop when you didn't need it? I see this *all the time* on SO, and I don't understand it. Do you just copy code from other programs, without actually understanding why it's written the way it is?

And get in the habit of *always* putting braces around the body of `if`, `while`, `foreach`, etc. statements, even if there's only one statement in the body. That way, when you add a second statement, you won't run the risk of forgetting to add braces around them, which I suspect is how you ended up in this mess.

Also, use a decent IDE, whose editor indents the code to mirror the structure. Then you'd probably notice that the second statement wasn't in the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I didn't realise about the braces, I c&p'd the code from somewhere where it was working and just changed the variables - didn't even consider what I was trying to get from the db